# How to enable Android emulator (AVD) microphone on OSX?

Tags: android, android-emulator, osx-lion, audio-recording

This question was somewhat asked [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924190/how-do-you-enable-a-microphone-input-in-the-android-emulator) but it doesn't appear there was a resolution.

For testing purposes, I am trying to use an app on the Android emulator that records from the mic. I believe this is possible -- but correct me if I'm wrong.

Using the following combinations, I have been unsuccessful in running the Speech Recognition app (app closes when I hit record with Sorry! message):

host os - OSX lion / Fedora
android os - 2.0, 4.3

My mic is working on the host machine. I have enabled audio recording and playback in the AVD.

Comment: Have you started the emulator manually? See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html for startup options. You can get a list of valid audio backends with -`help-audio-in`.

Comment: `-help-audio-in` doesn't appear to be available in the latest emulator version. Closest is `-help-audio` but that doesn't provide a list of devices. What does a valid device string look like?